# How to sum the values of same key from txt file using python

Tags: python

I am trying to sum up values of same key from txt file

The txt file looks like

```
   **record count**
   |
   ** Type**
   --|--
   4
   |
   Employee

   3
   |
   Employee
  
   8 
   |
   Post

   6
   | 
   Post
```

I want to sum the employee record count and post record count

Expected output is

```
   Employee: 7
   Post :14
```

My code is :

```
   Dataa ={'Employee':0, 'Post':0}
   With open('new.txt', 'r') as f_in:
   for line in map(str.strip, f_in) 
     if not line:
       continue
     name, cnt =line.split()
     if name not in Dataa:
        Dataa[name] =int(cnt) 
     else:
        Dataa[name]+=int(cnt) 
   for name in sorted(Dataa):
      Print(name, Dataa[name])
```

But i am getting below error

```
name, cnt=line.split() 
ValueError: too many values to unpack(excepted 2)
```

Please help me with solution.

Comment: Your code is definitely what you've pasted in here, because it has multiple syntax errors, and wouldn't run.

Comment: Please also give a verbatim example of the text file – unless your text file _really_ contains `**record count**` and `|` lines.

Comment: That is not the error you're getting (unless Python has introduced spelling errors in its exception reporting)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex` to parse your text file:

```
import re

with open('new.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

for name in ['Employee', 'Post']:
    res = re.findall(f'(\d+)\n\|\n{name}', data)
    print(f'{name}: {sum([int(e) for e in res])}')
```

Output:

```
Employee: 7
Post: 14
```

Comment: But i am getting output with 0  values I. e, employee 0 post 0

Comment: Can you share your text file somewhere and provide me with the link? Seems it has different format from what you've posted in question.